# alternate dates between 2 dates Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to find the Alternate Days between 2 dates.
here is my Jquery code which finds the total number of hours between dates.

```
var strt_date="2016-02-03";
                var end_date = "2016-02-08";
                strt_date = new Date(strt_date);
                end_date = new Date(end_date); 
                var hours=Math.abs(strt_date - end_date) / 36e5;
                console.log(hours);
```

how do i find the alternate dates between these 2 dates

UPDATE:The output look like this 
 2016-02-03 
 2016-02-05
 2016-02-07
alternate dates between 2 dates  starting from selected date

Comment: What do you mean by the "alternate dates"?

Answer (score 0):

```
var start   = new Date("2016-02-03");
var end     = new Date("2016-02-08");
var between = [];
var mil     = 86400000 //24h
var init    = 0;
for (var i=start.getTime(); i<end.getTime();i=i+mil) {
    if(init%2==0) between.push(new Date(i));
    //if(init%2==0) between.push(indDate.getFullYear()+"-"+(indDate.getMonth()+1)+"-"+indDate.getDate());
    //above condition returns the dates in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format
    init++; 
}
console.log(between);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Wed Feb 03 2016 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
Fri Feb 05 2016 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
Sun Feb 07 2016 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
//this date format can be changed to required one, while you push content to the array
```

Check the above code, all the above things go normal here, like i added `for` loop in order to achieve range in an array, add a condition under the looping statement to get only alternate number of days.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do something like this:

```
var strt_date="2016-02-03";
var end_date = "2016-02-08";
strt_date = new Date(strt_date);
end_date = new Date(end_date); 
var timeDiff = Math.abs(strt_date.getTime() - end_date.getTime());
var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
var alt_date = new Date(strt_date);
alt_date.setDate(strt_date + diffDays/2); //here you have the date between
```

Comment: your code does not work, undefined vars date1 and date2

Answer (score 0):

To make sure that you don't have any issues with the local time settings messing you up, you'll want to set time to midnight first.  You can also take advantage of the fact that `setHours(24)` will set the date to midnight of the next day, rather than messing around with getTime() and adding 86400000 milliseconds.

```
var start   = new Date("2016-02-03");
var end     = new Date("2016-02-08");
start.setHours(24);
end.setHours(0);
var between = [];
while(start.setHours(24) <= end) {
  between.push(new Date(start));
}
console.log(between);
```